# CSS fade-in, instant hide

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, fadein

I am trying to build a class that I can easily slap onto an element that would fade the element into view when it is rendered but instantly hide it when I set `display` to none.

So far, the classes Ive build fade the element into view, but there is a slight delay on hiding OR the element fade-hides as well.

I have this so far using animations for the class `fadeIn`:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
   from    { opacity: 0; }
   to      { opacity: 1; }
}

.fadeIn { 
   animation: fadeIn 0.2s both ease-in; 
}
```

This one fades-in but there is a delay when hiding it

Another one looks like this:

```
.fade-show {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

This doesnt actually fade-in and delays on hide.

I would just like something to fade when rendered or `display` set to `block` but instantly hide when `display` set to `none`.

Usage for this class would be as follows:

```
<div class="fadeIn" >I fade in but dont fade on hide</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Enjoy :)

You have also this library of animations, it's very nice and simply to use!

> Animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

```css
.fadeMe {
  animation:fadeIn 1s linear;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

.fadeMe.none {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<div class="fadeMe">Fade in (try to add none after the class?)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use KeyFrames to achieve this.

Set the initial `opacity` of the element to 0.
Add a class (`.show`) to the element which sets the `opacity` to 1 and adds the `transition` attributes.

Note, if you were to add the transitions to the 'div' CSS selector instead of the .show class then it would fade in AND out.

Add/remove the `.show` class to show/hide the element.

HTML:

```
<div class="show" >I fade in but dont fade on hide</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: The element remains in the dom if you don't set `display: none;` this will effect layout in flexbox for example.